# stylelint giving error on iOs - Error: Could not find "stylelint-config-standard". Do you need a `configBasedir`?

Tags: ios, stylelint

It works ok on ubuntu

I installed stylelint on iOS but when I run it I get

Error: Could not find "stylelint-config-standard". Do you need a `configBasedir`?

My config file is:

```
$ cat .stylelintrc.json
{
  "extends": "stylelint-config-standard",
  "rules": {
    "rule-empty-line-before": null,
    "at-rule-empty-line-before": null
  }
}
```

I tried `"extends": ["stylelint-config-standard"],`
but it didn't help

Answer (score 4):

I had that error message until I installed the *config*

npm install stylelint-config-standard --save-dev

Comment: For global usage, the configuration has to be installed with `npm i stylelint-config-standard --globalconfig --save-dev`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the `stylelint-config-standard` dependency installed already, maybe you need to delete the `node_modules` folder and `package-lock.json` or `yarn.lock` if you're using yarn, and run the following command:

```
npm install
```

or with yarn

```
yarn install
```

if the `stylelint-config-standard` dependency isn't installed may you need to install it running:

```
npm install stylelint-config-standard -D
```

or with yarn

```
yarn add stylelint-config-standard -D
```

Comment: Clarifying how to remove node_modules and package-lock.json and npm install:
rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json && npm install

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was adding the **overrides** section to the config:

```
module.exports = {
    overrides: [
        {
            files: ["**/*.scss"],
            customSyntax: "postcss-scss"
        }
    ],
    rules: {...},
}
```

Answer (score -2):

First, as tried, change the `extends` to be

```
"extends": ["stylelint-config-standard"],
```

but then also do `npm install`

Comment: Didn't work for me